# Invalid printer specified (sometimes it's working, other times it won't)

Tags: vb.net, printing

I'm trying to print from a selected network printer. Sometimes it's working, but other times it won't print, giving me the following error:

> "Invalid printer specified.MyCrystalRPTfilename 11124_5324_{67F07633-5EF3-49B4-9573-BB34151D75BA}.rpt"

I found the different parts of the code below from the net. **I know that this was asked here before but the solutions given doesn't work for me**, maybe I just missed something.

```
Try

            Dim PrintDialog1 As New PrintDialog
            PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()
            PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName

            Dim prtdoc As New PrintDocument
            Dim strDefaultPrinter As String = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName


            Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
            Dim crtableLogoninfos As New TableLogOnInfos
            Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo
            Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo
            Dim CrTables As Tables
            Dim CrTable As Table
            cryRpt.Load("C:\path\of\my\report\MyCrystalRPTfilename.rpt")

            With crConnectionInfo
                .ServerName = "myserver"
                .DatabaseName = "mydbase"
                .UserID = "myuser"
                .Password = "mypassword"
            End With

            CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables
            For Each CrTable In CrTables
                crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
            Next

            cryRpt.Refresh()
            cryRpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = strDefaultPrinter
            cryRpt.PrintOptions.PaperSource = CrystalDecisions.[Shared].PaperSource.Auto
            cryRpt.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 1, 1)


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString())
        End Try
```

Comment: looking at this, I notice you have `PrintDocument1`, `prtdoc` and `cryRpt` what are the first 2 doing? Also, for troubleshooting, what is the printer name when it fails and when it succeeds?

Comment: @reckface forgot to comment the first two, I didn't use that. While troubleshooting, the printer name is the one I select, strdefaultPrinter value is the printer name. Looks like this: "\\network\sharedprintername", Before giving me the exception, it ends in this part: cryRpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = strDefaultPrinter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the printer you intend to use actually exists at the time of the print:
Try checking with this:

```
if Not PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.OfType(Of String)().Any(Function (s) s.Equals(strDefaultPrinter)) Then
  ' Display/handle an error
End If
```

**EDIT**

Ok, depending on the version in use, SAP recommends changing to use the `PrintOutputController` API stating that `PrintToPrinter` is no longer actively developed or supported:

1. Reference `CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers` and `CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc`
2. Create a Print options object with information about the default printer

   ```
   Dim options = New PrintReportOptions With
   {
       .PrinterName = strDefaultPrinter,
       .Collated = False,
       .NumberOfCopies = 1,
       .JobTitle = report.Name
   }
   ' pass the options to the print method
   report.ReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.PrintReport(options)
   ' If you're done
   report.Close()
   report.Dispose()
   ```

Comment: Hi. I did this. And it shows that the shared printer exists. By the way, the printer is a shared network printer, if it means anything.

Comment: if it exists, is it still failing?

Comment: yes, still fails. That's why I don't know how to debug it now even if it gets the right printer.

Comment: I added SAP's recommendation